# How to Use PostAsync and ReadAsStringAsync in Asp.Net Console Application at the time of request and response for other server?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api2, console-application

I create a one Web Service to get token to another server. Another server is created on Node. 
I use the username and password for credential and grant-type is client_credentials and get token for the current server.

The code for request

```
var request = await client.PostAsync("http://203.100.80.130:2300/nodeapi/Login", requestBody);
```

The code for the response

```
var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But I don't know the exatly meaning of both the method.
I hope anyone found the solution.

Comment: Did you even try reading the docs for [`PostAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=netframework-4.8) or [`ReadAsStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: yes, I read both the method in docs.microsoft. But I don't know about exactly use for both the method

Comment: The docs explain it, what more do you need?!

Comment: I found some problem can you help me out.

Comment: If you have a problem, then ask that question, don't ask things that are explained by simple docs.

Comment: ohk, I remember that things next time

Comment: If you already asked, what is the point of this question?

Comment: you know about this issue

Comment: I'll ask again... If you already asked, what is the point of this question?

Comment: First I ask the whole issue then I realize the exact issue on both the method on this question so I ask the question here anyone know both the method exact use on the program. So I ask.

Comment: In docs.microsoft is not providing more details for this both method

Answer (score -1):

Please check the requestBody. You are doing it right. Mostly there will be minor mistake in creating the requestBody.

Comment: It's issue on requestBody Parameter.